# MvvmCross Dialog Custom UIViewElement Databinding

Tags: mvvmcross

I am trying to set up databinding code for a MvxView passed into a UIViewElement, using this [Github Example Code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DialogExamples/DialogExamples.Touch/BindableElements/CustomViewElement.cs) as a basis

I have this Element -

```
public class WGMvxViewElement : UIViewElement, IBindableElement
{
    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }

    public WGMvxViewElement(string caption, MvxView view, bool transparent)
        : base(caption, view, transparent)
    {
        this.CreateBindingContext();

        // Bind our DataContext to the DataContext of the supplied MvxView

        this.DelayBind(() => {

            view.DataContext = DataContext;

        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            BindingContext.ClearAllBindings();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public virtual object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

Does the current code in DelayBind cause any Memory Leaks or issues?

I was originally trying to use Databinding to do this rather than an explicit set, but could not get the syntax to work / was causing error / loops

```
this.DelayBind(() => {
    this.CreateBinding().For(mvxve => mvxve.DataContext).To<SettingsProfileView>(v => v.DataContext).Apply();
    // think that was in reverse, so try?
    view.CreateBinding().For(v => v.DataContext).To<WGMvxViewElement>(ve => ve.DataContext);
```

Can anyone correct me if this is wrong or has the appropriate binding code so its binding all the way down?

I then do this in my Dialog -

```
public class SettingsView : MvxDialogViewController
{
    SettingsViewModel MyViewModel { get { return ViewModel as SettingsViewModel; } }

    public SettingsView() : base(UITableViewStyle.Plain, null, true)
    {
        MvxInlineBindingTarget<SettingsViewModel> bindings = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<SettingsViewModel>();

        Root = new RootElement("Settings")
        {
            new Section("Section") {
                 new WGMvxViewElement("", new SettingsProfileView(), true).Bind(bindings, el => el.DataContext, vm => vm),  

    ...
```

The supplied view to WGMvxViewElement will then use this DataContext something like so in its ctor -

```
public SettingsProfileView ()
{
    ... profileUIImageView + View set up somehow

    this.DelayBind (() => {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SettingsProfileView, SettingsViewModel>();
        set.Bind(profileUIImageView.Tap()).For(tap => tap.Command).To(vm => vm.ChooseProfileCommand);
        set.Apply(); 
    });
}
```

Whilst composing this question, the code seems to be functioning OK, but are there any shortcomings or improvements that can be seen by experienced users, like have I missed the point somewhere.

Comment: `Does the current code in DelayBind cause any Memory Leaks or issues?` I can't see any issues looking at it as a block of text - looks good. If you've got an app up and running using this, then I guess you'll be able to see the real answer yourself.

Comment: Thank you Stuart I appreciate the comment, yes I do have it running now, and will memory test it in the end, just was not sure due to lack of understanding If I needed to Databind the DataContext vs explicitly set the Datacontext.